# Best way to Hide and Restore an Application

Tags: delphi, vcl

I would like to hide my entire Application and then later restore it back to the state it was (Kinda like minimize to Tray).
This includes all opened forms and an included Modal Form. It should also hide each form's taskbar visibility. I can hide the MainForm, but what about the other forms and the modal form? What would be the easiest way to hide dynamically all forms and restore them back to the state how they were?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I would assume two reasons - First of all, you had "hidden requirements" which is additional details that you added later after someone answered. Second of all, it's so trivial to do a search and find the answer for your questions online. On another note, if you have multiple different forms showing icons in the taskbar, then you must have some code (which we cannot see) doing that, because by default only the main form shows in the taskbar. In order for us to answer your question, we need to know how you're showing those forms in order to know how to hide them.

Comment: @JerryDodge- Anyone can say "google it". Instead of pointing to google you could have provide a real answer as David did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call `Application.Minimize` and `Application.Restore` to perform these actions.

To remove a form from the taskbar, hide it. Assuming that you have  `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` set to `True`, and only the main form associated with the taskbar, you can use `Application.MainForm.Visible := False`. Reverse this when you call `Application.Restore`.

So, in summary, to go dark:

```
Application.Minimize;
Application.MainForm.Visible := False;
```

And to reappear:

```
Application.MainForm.Visible := True;
Application.Restore;
```

If you have more than one form associated with the taskbar, you'd need to hide those forms too to remove the button from the task bar.

Comment: I don't want to minimize the Application. I want to hide it.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the difference is. Because when you execute  `Application.Minimize`, all the forms disappear from sight.

Comment: Yes. But the MainForm is still in the taskbar even if I use `Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := FALSE;`

Comment: Nothing in the question says that you want to remove the main form from the task bar. This is the answer to the question that you asked, so far as I can tell.

Comment: I've edited my question. Just hiding the MainForm won't do it, thus other forms are still visible.

Comment: You have more than one form on the taskbar?

Comment: I do, however it seem to work just fine. Thank you very much. I didn't know I had to minimize them.

Comment: Nope, it works just fine for a form without biMinimize. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. If I remember, subforms aren't visible in taskbar. Try change forms visibility in your project options.

```
function HideFromTaskbar(hWnd: HWND): Boolean;
begin
  if SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) = 0 then
    Result := False
  else
    Result := True;
end;

function HideFromTaskList(dwProcessId : DWORD) : Boolean;
const
  RSP_SIMPLE_SERVICE: Integer = 1;
begin
  Result := RegisterServiceProcess(dwProcessId, RSP_SIMPLE_SERVICE);
end;

ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
```

Comment: That's the wrong way to remove a window from the taskbar. You simply need to set its visibility to `False`. What's more, you don't deal with window re-creation, which will always bite you on the backside somewhere down the line.

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works. You are meant to answer the question that was asked. [faq]

Comment: Maybe I don't understand question, but I think so that this code is part of answer for hiding application from tasks list.

Comment: Perhaps this code could help, but how are we to know why it would. You need to do more than just dump code. You need to explain. For example, what is `RegisterServiceProcess`? Why does it help? How do you reverse it?

Comment: @Radoslav.B, if you don't understand the question as you just said then you should not be posting an answer.

Comment: Exactly, if you need clarification of the question, then ask the OP questions in the comments before posting what you think the OP might want.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you do realize that this could also be for making some ransom-ware. Is there a moral point where assistance is given or denied? To me, hiding the entire app means that it can only be restored with another app that will undo the complete hidden nature. It make no sense to me anyway, for an app to be hidden completely and forever.

Comment: @user2175495 I know many many applications which work this way.

Comment: @user2175495 It's just an app hiding itself and leaving notification area icon.